# Mongorestore command doesn't work as expected

Tags: mongodb, mlab, mongorestore

i am trying to import my database to my mongoLab database, but it keep showing the following error:

```
2016-10-19T21:05:49.183+0800    Failed: error connecting to db server: server returned error on SASL authentication step: Authentication failed.
-bash: vd: command not found
```

This is how I ran my command:

```
mongorestore -h 243253423.mlab.com:2131242 -d meteor -u <Username> -p <Password> /Users/directory/desktop/mongo/dump
```

Comment: Are you using the correct database user credentials (not to be confused with mLab account credentials)? If so, mLab support can help you pinpoint the issue: support@mlab.com

Comment: @pneumee yes, and doing so, I will contact them now, thanks

Comment: Are you able to connect using mongo shell?

Comment: @andresk yes I am able to connect to mongo shell

Comment: You may need to include `--authenticationDatabase admin` flag possibly?

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this error message and I am not sure this was your specific problem but this ended up working for me

```
mongorestore -d production-db \
   -u myusername -p MyPassword \
   --authenticationDatabase admin --host mydomain.com \
   ~/tmp/mongodump/local-production-db/
```

(be sure to check firewall `sudo ufw status` and net.bindIp `sudo nano /etc/mongod.conf` to confirm that you have access and your mongo process is listening on an external port)